# Indexing Related Entities Using Zend Lucene

Tags: zend-framework, symfony1, lucene, propel, zend-lucene

I have set up search in my application, but wish to expand it to index properties related in a one-to-many way. For instance, a person can have many usernames, so they have to be kept separate, as in the following example:

```
person:
  id:         ~
  name:       {type: varchar(100), required: true}

username:
  person_id:  {type: integer, foreignTable: person, foreignReference: id}
  username:   {type: varchar(20), primaryKey: true, required: true}
```

So far I have followed the [Jobeet example](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/17) to use Zend Lucene within my application, and I can search on properties of name within Person, such as Name.

I couldn't find any way to do this automatically through Symfony or Lucene, so I attempted to add the items in the Person's index like so:

```
foreach ($this->getUsernames() as $i => $username)
{
  $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('username' . $i,
      $username->getUsername(), 'utf-8'));
}
```

I then attempted to update this index whenever a new Username is added by updating Username's save function:

```
public function save(PropelPDO $con = null)
{
  $ret = parent::save($con);

  // reindex the person
  $person = $this->getPerson();
  $person->save();

  return $ret;
}
```

This works fine as long as the person is created at run-time, but if loaded from fixtures, `getUsernames()` returns nothing. The code is executed twice (once while loading Person, and once when adding the Username). Is there any reason for this? Can I get around this somehow?

Another way of doing this would also be appreciated. It appears that Lucene can search over multiple indices using the Zend_Lucene_Search_Interface_MultiSearcher class, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705230/search-multiple-indices-at-once-using-lucene-search). However, I can't seem to get this working.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864161/symfony-with-zend-lucene-and-related-models-with-foreign-keys), but found no pointers.

I am now using Propel 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which propel version you are using. Seeing you are using PDO, you most likely are using 1.3+.

if the Username object is initialized right, that is:

```
<?php
$username = new Username();
$username->setUsername('foobar');
$username->setPerson($person);
```

Calling $username->save(); should trigger also save() for the $person, and also the $person object should contain the Username object.

But what comes to the $person initialization, there is a "feature". (some might call it a bug..)

If you initialize $person like:

```
$person = PersonPeer::retrieveByPk(123);
//or for 1.5+
$person = PersonQuery::create()->findPk(123);
```

the $person's Usernames-list will be empty. And when you call

```
 $username->setPerson($person);
```

the $username will be added to the $person's Usernames-list, which in turn means calling $person->getUsernames() won't automatically fetch the usernames from db, as the list is already non-empty.

So you need to initialize $person with the usernames. Either like

```
<?php
$person = PersonQuery::create()->joinWith('Person.Usernames')->filterById(123)->findOne();
```

or

```
<?php
$person = PersonPeer::retrieveByPk(123);
$person->getUsernames(); //trigger list fetch
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Unfortunately, I don't see how to apply this to my problem. The only function I am currently overriding in Username.php is `save()`, which currently looks exactly like I posted. If I don't call `$person->save()` myself, it doesn't at all. Are you suggesting it should?

Where should I be putting the above initialisation of Person? In Username's `setPerson()`, or overriding `doSave()`?

Comment: Hmm.. it seems I remembered wrong this behavior.. On my example case calling $username->setPerson($person); actually calls $person->addUsername($username); which actually then initializes the collection. At least on 1.5+. So for initializing the collection you shouldn't have to do anything special. Your code then should work. The username-collection should be fully initialized in your persons' save-method. The person's save-method is only called if the person is actually modified, so that you have to call manually, as you are doing.

Comment: Do you know why else the usernames might not have been initialised in Person?